# Change calculation on switch

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to make this grafic work, but I'm some kind of a new in this whole thing so I have a few things that I can't get to work.

The idea is simple. When you drag on the first input[range] a calculation is made. The answer it's after the "round slider".
When you switch to "No" the formula is changing, so the calculation it's made with values from both "R&D Spend" and "Business Losses".

So...if I select value=5m at "R&D Spend" the calculation is: 750,000.
If I select value=5m at "R&D Spend", select "No" and then select value=5m at "Business Losses" the calculation is: 2,250,000.

But in this stage, if I switch the switch button back to 'YES' the second input[range] dissapears(which is good), but the calculation it's still the second one, not the first one, just with value from the first input.

You can see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1x60sp0a/4/

```
$('#js--checkbox').change(function(e) {
  if ($('#js--checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $('#slider2').slideDown();
    } else {
    $('#slider2').slideUp();
    }
});
```

I hope I've explained well.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I checked and the checkbox change handler is called, I don't really get how you tell your code to make the computation again (since the `slideDown`/`slideUp` are not doing). Any other event listeners ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a trigger thah runs when you select 'yes' at checkbox

```
$('#js--checkbox').change(function(e) {
    if ($('#js--checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $('#slider2').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('#slider2').slideUp();
        $('#flying2').val('0').trigger('change');
        $('#slider2out').text(0);
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2gz09mk/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what if you check back to 'No'. Can it go back to the calculation with both of the sliders?
So..first slider value 5m - Answer: 750k. 
Check 'No'.
First slider value = 5m / Second slider value = 5m - Answer: 2,250k
Check 'Yes' - Answer goes to first answer: 750k
Check 'No' again - second slider goes to the previous value selected and the Answer: 2,250k.
And so on, on every 'switch'. It's a thing for that? Thanks again?

Comment: I don't have words to thank you. And I really understood the code. Thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend something like triggering a change and then resetting the text to update your range when you uncheck your checkbox, such as the following:

```
$('#js--checkbox').change(function(e) {
  if ($('#js--checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $('#slider2').slideDown();
  } else {
    $('#slider2').slideUp();
    $('#flying2').val(0).trigger('change');
    $('#slider2out').text(0);
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x60sp0a/8/)

I'd recommend even making this a "reset" function to make it a little more usable / understandable.

Damn - just noticed I got beaten by like 30 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what if you check back to 'No'. Can it go back to the calculation with both of the sliders?
So..first slider value 5m - Answer: 750k. 
Check 'No'.
First slider value = 5m / Second slider value = 5m - Answer: 2,250k
Check 'Yes' - Answer goes to first answer: 750k
Check 'No' again - second slider goes to the previous value selected and the Answer: 2,250k.
And so on, on every 'switch'. It's a thing for that? Thanks again?

Comment: @k3r0 If that's what you're after, your best bet would be to store the values in variables before you reset them with `.val(0)` and `.text(0)` then place them back when you check it again. You'll obviously want to have an if statement to check that they exist first too.